# Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3

Tags: rubygems

I just cloned a project with Ruby 2.2.3. My installed Ruby version is 2.3.0.
Is there any manipulation which allowed me to work on the project without changing my installed version ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using a ruby version manager? If so, you could alias your 2.3.0 to 2.2.3 to trick the Gemfile. Or just install 2.2.3 along side it and keep going.

Comment: Thanks Philippe for you answer. I found the solution in between. I could say to ruby ro use the repo version by this command `rbenv local 2.2.3` in the project file

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in between. 
I could specify to use the repo version for this project by this command in the project file.

```
$ rbenv local 2.2.3
```

That's mean :"for this project, use this version of Ruby". Of course don't forget to specify the version that you want to use